# JQuery Animation overlay issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello I have an odd problem, I have an animation that opens up over top of a website, however after it is done opening, none of the links that where under the overlay seem to work.  I have created a jsfiddle to demonstrate the issue.

[Fiddle me this!](http://jsfiddle.net/fFaac/)

```
    var removeWhenOpen = true; var done = false;
var timer0;
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('#doors').hover(function() {
        jQuery('#door-left').stop().animate({left:-500}, 1500, function() { if (removeWhenOpen) $(this).remove(); done=true; });
        jQuery('#door-right').stop().animate({right:-500}, 1500, function() { if (removeWhenOpen) $(this).remove(); });
        var timer0 = setTimeout(function() {
            jQuery('#ladyonthelake').stop().animate({opacity:0}, 2000);
        }, 5);
    }, function() {
        jQuery('#door-left').stop().animate({left:0}, 250);
        jQuery('#door-right').stop().animate({right:0}, 250);
        if (!done) {
            if (timer0) clearTimeout(timer0);
            jQuery('#ladyonthelake').stop().fadeIn();
        }
    })
});


<div id="doors">
            <img src="http://theitentrepreneurs.com/temp/ladyonthelake.jpg" width="347" height="520" border="0" id="ladyonthelake" />
            <div id="door-left" class="door"><div class="inner"></div><img src="http://theitentrepreneurs.com/temp/doorleft.png" /></div>
            <div id="door-right" class="door"><div class="inner"></div><img src="http://theitentrepreneurs.com/temp/doorright.png" /></div>
        </div>
```

any help would be greatly appreciated, as always my back is up against the wall on time, so anything anyone can offer would be great!

Thanks
Bryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem was that the doors div was not being removed after the animation was completed causing there to be an absolutely positioned element above the links obstructing the clickability.

add this

```
jQuery('#door-left').stop().animate({left:-500}, 1500, function() { if (removeWhenOpen) $("#doors").remove(); done=true; });
```

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/gravitybox/fFaac/1/

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to remove `$('#doors')`.